# Why checkbox's state does not change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, checkbox

The click of checkbox will send a ajax request to server, and here is how I process the toggle:

```
toggleDefault: function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(e.target).data('target');
            var value = $(e.target).attr('checked') ? 0 : 1;
            $.post(url, {value: value})
                .done(function() {
                    value ? $(e.target).attr('checked', true) : $(e.target).removeAttr('checked');
                })
                .error(function() {
                    alert('There is an error processing request, please try again.');
                })
        }
```

The disable event does work fine. But when it comes to the enable event, I can see the `$(e.target).attr('checked', true)` action changes the checkbox dom. But the checkbox on UI is still unclicked.
[image]
[image]

How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.done(function() {
   value ? $(e.target).prop('checked', true) : $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
})
```

Also changed this line `var value = $(e.target).attr('checked') ? 0 : 1;` to `var value = $(e.target).is(':checked') ? 0 : 1;`.

Hope this will works!

Comment: `var value = $(e.target).is(':checked') ? 0 : 1;` fails to get the right state.

Comment: When it's checked you want 0 and when not checked  you want 1 right? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. But I get 0 when unchecked.

Comment: OK then toggle the value: `var value = $(e.target).is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;` Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/9ss85w2u/3/).

Comment: The thing is, she is using eventpreventDefault() function, so it will be 0 everytime you click on it

Comment: It works. So `$(e.target).is(':checked')` get true when it is unchecked. That's wired.

Comment: Yes, `e.preventDefault();` remove this line. I have already removed that in my fiddle.

Comment: Remove `e.preventDefault();` and try @JasmineOT

Comment: And if the ajax call failed then in `error` method just revert the check status.

Comment: WOW. So that's the tricky part! @MarvinHeilemann and Deepak Thanks you two very much.

Answer (score 1):

I edited your code a bit. The thing is you are using `e.eventpreventDefault();` so your `:checked`-toggle cant work. The browser will set it to the default value every time your event is called.

```js
$("#ckb").click(function (e) {
//toggleDefault: function(e) {
  // e.preventDefault();
  var url = $(e.target).data('target');
  var value = $(e.target).prop('checked') ? 0 : 1;
  $.post(url, {value: value})
    .done(function() {
      if(value===0) {
        $(e.target).prop('checked', true);
      } else {
        $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
      }
    })
    .error(function() {
      alert('There is an error processing request, please try again.');
    })
//}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" name="default" id="ckb">Set as default
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you refer somewhere that I can figure out how `preventDefault` stops me from reading current state?

Answer (score 0):

You should not change attribute, it will not work. Instead change the `prop` [property](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (check "Attributes vs. Properties" section):

```
value ? $(e.target).prop('checked', true) : $(e.target).prop('checked', false);
```

Or if simplified it will be just:

```
.done(function() {
    $(e.target).prop('checked', Boolean(value));
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried this before. The problem is: first time is ok. But when I click the checkbox second time without refreshing page, the value get by `$(e.target).attr('checked')` will be wrong.

Comment: Read also using the `prop` property: `$(e.target).prop('checked')`. When you change / read the checked **attribute**, it only affects the **default** (hence initial) state of your checkbox, not the current one.

Comment: I tried your method again and found that the dom of checkbox is unchanged in this way. So do you know the way to change the current state of checkbox? Or must I refresh the page?